# How to shotdown a worker on heroku when using resque/keepalive branch?

Tags: heroku, resque, keep-alive

I am new at heroku and resque.

I have a queue in resque and i should hire and release workers according to current amount of jobs in my queue automatically. I tried hirefireapp but it just hire workers while queue expands and not release any worker unless there are no job waiting in queue. So i make some research and find out that  there is no way to say a worker not take a new job after finished current one and shutdown yourself. Resque developers and users also have pointed out this issue in this link https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/319 and create a new branch which is keepalive to resque ( https://github.com/hone/resque/tree/keepalive ). It seems it is the solution for my issue. However, since i am new in using resque i couldn't find out that how to fire a worker via resque safely.

If anyone who have  more experienced in resque and heroku help me, i will be really glad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to run a separate process to control the scaling of workers.

[resque-heroku-scaler](https://github.com/spiro/resque-heroku-scaler) is one option.

A single additional scaler process helps you manage workers efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really what Resque is designed for as it's meant to be sitting there working a queue, not deciding whether or not to start up/shut down.

Personally, unless the money required to run the worker 24/7 is that hard to come by I would just leave it running.